# Condense "flat" list of occurrences for analysis with arules eclat

Tags: r

I have a file that looks like this (list of person ID and product name)

```
123   A
123   B
123   D
456   A
456   B
123   C
```

And I'd like to convert it for use with eclat to something like this (list of products each person purchased)

```
list(
   c("A", "B", "D", "C"),
   c("A", "B" )
 )
```

The best I've been able to do is to read it as a data frame, and attempt using the variants of the apply function to make the new data strucutre.

```
collectValues <- function(obs,map) {
  a = obs[1][1]
  b = obs[2][1]
  if( ! (a %in% map) ) {
    map[[a]] <- list(b)
  } else {
    c(map[[a]], b)
  }
}
```

but I'm too new to R to get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after `split` as in:

```
dat <- read.table(text="123   A
123   B
123   D
456   A
456   B
123   C", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lapply(split(dat[, 2], dat[, 1]), sort)

## $`123`
## [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
## 
## $`456`
## [1] "A" "B"
```

I used the `lapply` with `sort` as that's what you're desired output looked like but you may not need it.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you. For eclat, the sort does not seem to be required...